# How to create Location object

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I am trying to make a new location and set its latitude/longitude like this:

```
var targetlocation = Location("")
//this example code doesn't work below
targetlocation.setLatitude(55.555555)
targetlocation.setLongitude(55.555555)
```

How can I do this correctly in kotlin? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the problem exist in above code? There seems no issue here.

Comment: I keep getting expecting member declaration

Comment: @Noop Seems you did not declared something correctly, BUT that is not in the code which you shared.

Comment: I figured out the error I declared the variable outside of a function, but i then changed it to inside. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but try doing this.

```
var targetlocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
targetlocation.latitude = 55.555555
targetlocation.longitude = 55.555555
```

Comment: Hi I tried that already but i get "expecting member declaration" error

Comment: I still get the same error could it be an Android Studio issue?